# do thumbnail image styles lower the page load

Tags: media

This may not be a Drupal specific question, but when I use image styles to resize from a full to thumbnail size, will the page load still behave as if its a hiqh quality image, or does it lower the page load?

I'm trying to figure out if there should ever be a reason to provide two upload fields on a content type, one for a high quality image and one for a lower one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploaded images are scaled depending on the preset you choose for display. Thus, a typical high resolution image which might have 8 MB is reduced to maybe 150 kB when using a thumbnail preset. This of course lowers the bandwidth, the original image is not loaded.

So, there is no need to create a second image field. If you haven't seen it yet, you might want to take a look at the [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) module. It lets you choose to display an image as a thumbnail and only upon clicking on that preview the full image is loaded (or just another size you defined).

Just a note: Colorbox is not the only module that is providing that feature, there are a lot of similar modules, the original was called Lightbox. On drupal.org, there's a [page comparing all available lightbox clones](https://www.drupal.org/node/266126).

Answer (score 1):

Using thumbnail image, your page load time will be decreased. You should use only one field to upload image.You can use different image styles in drupal.

By default, drupal provides your three images styles.

1)Thumbnail

2)Medium

3)Large

You can also create more image styles at following page.

Click on Configuration-> Media->Image Style. Click on Add style link.